# how to avoid automatic grammar correction in whisper openai

Tags: speech-recognition, openai-api, transcription, openai-whisper

Whisper corrects speech grammar automatically, who has ideas how can I disable that?

this is the code:

```
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const resp = await openai
    .createTranscription(
        fs.createReadStream(filePath),
        "whisper-1",
        undefined,
        "json",
    )
    .catch((resError) => {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(resError));
    });
```

Comment: I am having the same problem..Did you find out the solution?